Motivation for posting images of code/data/errors?
Posting images of code is a no no. Bandwidth, readability, and much more suffer when you do so. In all cases simply copying and pasting code to the text box is easier than taking a screenshot and uploading.
However, many inexperienced users upload images of code. My simple question is, why do they go though the effort of uploading the image of code anyway? What are the reasons people might upload an image of until they are enlightened of the guidelines against doing so?

I'm still a relatively new user of SO and MSO, but I think that people post images of their code either because they don't want to have to worry about the indentation being incorrect when they copy and paste or because they just don't know how they are supposed to/able to do it. If it's your first time posting a question, the markdown formatting can be confusing. "Do I use ``` at the beginning and the end?" "Do I do four spaces after every line of code?" It's things like these that might make it confusing for newbies posting their first questions.

They may believe that their question may that more experienced programmers can answer their question  by simply looking at the code, and do not consider that answerers may need to run the code.

Several reasons, and I'm afraid Ryan M's really sad reason is probably a prime one. But I also think that it is the act of people who treat errors as something scary rather than a friend. They snapshot it with all the colors and squigly lines in-tact. It is the act of not taking responsibility for understanding what part of the error is relevant to their case, they just want to shove it wholesale under your expert nose.

Re "Bandwidth, readability, and much more": Searchability is by far the most important. How are search engines supposed to match an error message to a question on Stack Overflow when the error message in that question is in an image? (Yes, that is a rhetorical question.)

My theory (based, admittedly, on very little evidence, though I've seen at least one person say that's the reason):
Users who have a lot of code and not a lot of text receive an "It looks like your post is mostly code, please add some more details" error, and an easy way to make that error go away is to replace it with an image.
It'd be great if the system provided some way to see what percentage of posts with images of code have hit this error, or otherwise test if this is indeed the cause.


My simple question is, why do they go though the effort of uploading the image of code anyway?

Other possible reasons:

Because they think it is easier and/or quicker than cut-and-pasting the text.  (And sometimes it objectively is; e.g. when they are using their mobile device to write a question.)
Because they think it looks nicer.
Because they are unfamiliar with Markdown; i.e. code blocks.
Because they didn't read the relevant parts of the Help Center page on asking questions, or read them and thought they knew better.

But I would posit that why they do it is moot.

If we are looking for solutions, maybe the Staging Ground could help with this.
It is not hard to detect a URL for one of the standard image hosting sites.  The Staging Ground could provide a way for the reviewer(s) to sign-off on the use of an image link in a new user's question.  (Not all uses of images are inappropriate, but an experienced SO can distinguish the good stuff from the bad.)  Without the sign-off, the user's question would be blocked automatically.
Or ... AI ... 'cos AI solves everything :-)
